# No puedo utlizar la tecla enter en android studio, solo puedo escribir pero no usar la tecla

Tags: android-studio

espero puedan ayudarme, estoy trabajando en android studio pero no sé que apreté y ya no puedo usar el enter, está bloqueado, me pueden ayudar, puedo escribir sin problemas los codigos pero no me deja dar enter para bajar por ejemplo a otra linea.

Comment: ¿Probaste volviendolo a abrir? También intenta [restablecer la configuración del teclado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183597/13419694) o [restablecer la configuración en general](https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-reset-android-studio-to-the-default-settings/)

Comment: me sirvió el restablecer la configuración del teclado